# File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analyse error in sonarqube 5.0

Tags: xml, msbuild, sonarqube

```
***I am trying to configure my project in derby sonar server(default). I
 run the MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin command followed by
 msbuild. I use MSBuild 14.0 and VS2015,c#-4.4,MSbuild 1.1,placed in
 path, win server 2012 envt(vli)

 Pre processing
```

> ```
>    >C:\Sonar
>     > db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn>MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe
> ```
>
> be gin /k:"Reklamfixarn" /n:"Reklamfixarn" /v:"1.0")
>
> SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1 Default properties file was found at
>   C:\Softwares\Ms build 1.1\MSBuild.SonarQube
>
> .Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
>
> Loading analysis properties from C:\Softwares\Ms build
>   1.1\MSBuild.SonarQube.Run
>
> ner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
>
> Pre-processing started. Preparing working directories... Checking for
>   updates... SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild Begin Step 1.1
>
> 06:39:15.634  Loading analysis properties from C:\Softwares\Ms build
>   1.1\MSBuild
>
> .SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
>
> 06:39:15.687  Updating build integration targets... 06:39:15.698 
>   Fetching analysis configuration settings... 06:39:16.851  Generating
>   rulesets... Pre-processing succeeded.
>
> msbuild uld vary based on the current user's locale settings, replace
>   this call in 'Xml Handler.ReturnAttributeValueFromXml(int, string,
>   XElement)' with a call to 'int .ToString(IFormatProvider)'. If the
>   result of 'int.ToString(IFormatProvider)' w ill be displayed to the
>   user, specify 'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' as the 'IFor matProvider'
>   parameter. Otherwise, if the result will be stored and accessed by 
>   software, such as when it is persisted to disk or to a database,
>   specify 'Cult ureInfo.InvariantCulture'. [C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL \BL.csproj]   C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(282): warni
>   ng CA1031: Microsoft.Design : Modify
>   'XmlHandler.ReturnCmykColor(string)' to ca tch a more specific
>   exception than 'Exception' or rethrow the exception. [C:\So nar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]   C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(50): warnin g
>   CA1031: Microsoft.Design : Modify
>   'XmlHandler.ReturnPhotographValue(XElement) ' to catch a more specific
>   exception than 'object' or rethrow the exception. [C :\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]   C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(90): warnin g
>   CA1011: Microsoft.Design : Consider changing the type of parameter
>   'XmlData' in 'XmlHandler.ReturnThemeColor(XElement)' from 'XElement'
>   to its base type 'XC ontainer'. This method appears to only require
>   base class members in its implem entation. Suppress this violation if
>   there is a compelling reason to require th e more derived type in the
>   method signature. [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerat
>   or\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]   C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(96): warnin g
>   CA1031: Microsoft.Design : Modify
>   'XmlHandler.ReturnThemeColor(XElement)' to catch a more specific
>   exception than 'object' or rethrow the exception. [C:\Son ar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]   C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(112): warni
>   ng CA1011: Microsoft.Design : Consider changing the type of parameter
>   'XmlData'  in 'XmlHandler.ReturnValueFromXml(int, XElement)' from
>   'XElement' to its base type 'XContainer'. This method appears to only
>   require base class members in it s implementation. Suppress this
>   violation if there is a compelling reason to re quire the more derived
>   type in the method signature. [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PD
>   FGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]   C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(115): warni
>   ng CA1305: Microsoft.Globalization : Because the behavior of
>   'int.ToString()' c ould vary based on the current user's locale
>   settings, replace this call in 'Xm lHandler.ReturnValueFromXml(int,
>   XElement)' with a call to 'int.ToString(IForma tProvider)'. If the
>   result of 'int.ToString(IFormatProvider)' will be displayed  to the
>   user, specify 'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' as the 'IFormatProvider'
>   par ameter. Otherwise, if the result will be stored and accessed by
>   software, such as when it is persisted to disk or to a database,
>   specify 'CultureInfo.Invarian tCulture'. [C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]   C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(233): warni
>   ng CA1011: Microsoft.Design : Consider changing the type of parameter
>   'xdoc' in  'XmlHandler.SplitXml(XDocument)' from 'XDocument' to its
>   base type 'XContainer '. This method appears to only require base
>   class members in its implementation . Suppress this violation if there
>   is a compelling reason to require the more d erived type in the method
>   signature. [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rekla
>   mfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]
>
> C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(233): warni
>   ng CA1002: Microsoft.Design : Change 'List' in
>   'XmlHandler.SplitX ml(XDocument)' to use Collection,
>   ReadOnlyCollection or KeyedCollection [C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]
>
> C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(247): warni
>   ng CA1305: Microsoft.Globalization : Because the behavior of
>   'Convert.ToInt32(s tring)' could vary based on the current user's
>   locale settings, replace this ca ll in
>   'XmlHandler.SplitXml(XDocument)' with a call to
>   'Convert.ToInt32(string, IFormatProvider)'. If the result of
>   'Convert.ToInt32(string, IFormatProvider)' will be based on input from
>   the user, specify 'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' as t he
>   'IFormatProvider' parameter. Otherwise, if the result will based on
>   input st ored and accessed by software, such as when it is loaded from
>   disk or from a da tabase, specify 'CultureInfo.InvariantCulture'.
>   [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGene rator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]
>
> C:\Sonar
>   db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(248): warni
>   ng CA1305: Microsoft.Globalization : Because the behavior of
>   'Convert.ToInt32(s tring)' could vary based on the current user's
>   locale settings, replace this ca ll in
>   'XmlHandler.SplitXml(XDocument)' with a call to
>   'Convert.ToInt32(string, IFormatProvider)'. If the result of
>   'Convert.ToInt32(string, IFormatProvider)' will be based on input from
>   the user, specify 'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' as t he
>   'IFormatProvider' parameter. Otherwise, if the result will based on
>   input st ored and accessed by software, such as when it is loaded from
>   disk or from a da tabase, specify 'CultureInfo.InvariantCulture'.
>   [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGene rator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]

```
>   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(162): warni
> ng CA1011: Microsoft.Design : Consider changing the type of parameter
> 'xAdress'  in 'XmlHandler.SplitXmlInOrders(XDocument, XDocument)' from
> 'XDocument' to its  base type 'XContainer'. This method appears to
> only require base class members  in its implementation. Suppress this
> violation if there is a compelling reason  to require the more derived
> type in the method signature. [C:\Sonar db\REC\Pos
> ten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(162): warni
> ng CA1011: Microsoft.Design : Consider changing the type of parameter
> 'xDoc' in  'XmlHandler.SplitXmlInOrders(XDocument, XDocument)' from
> 'XDocument' to its ba se type 'XContainer'. This method appears to
> only require base class members in  its implementation. Suppress this
> violation if there is a compelling reason to  require the more derived
> type in the method signature. [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten
> .PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]
> 
>     enter code here
> 
>   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(185): warni
> ng CA1031: Microsoft.Design : Modify
> 'XmlHandler.SplitXmlInOrders(XDocument, XD ocument)' to catch a more
> specific exception than 'Exception' or rethrow the ex ception.
> [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]  
> C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(162): warni
> ng CA1002: Microsoft.Design : Change 'List<PdfOrderHandler>' in
> 'XmlHandler.Spl itXmlInOrders(XDocument, XDocument)' to use
> Collection<T>, ReadOnlyCollection<T
>
```

> or KeyedCollection [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\ 
>   `Blockquote`BL.csproj]

```
> enter code here

>   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\XmlHandler.cs(200): warni
> ng CA1305: Microsoft.Globalization : Because the behavior of
> 'Convert.ToInt32(s tring)' could vary based on the current user's
> locale settings, replace this ca ll in
> 'XmlHandler.SplitXmlInOrders(XDocument, XDocument)' with a call to
> 'Conve rt.ToInt32(string, IFormatProvider)'. If the result of
> 'Convert.ToInt32(string,  IFormatProvider)' will be based on input
> from the user, specify 'CultureInfo.C urrentCulture' as the
> 'IFormatProvider' parameter. Otherwise, if the result wil l based on
> input stored and accessed by software, such as when it is loaded fro m
> disk or from a database, specify 'CultureInfo.InvariantCulture'.
> [C:\Sonar db \REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\BL\BL.csproj]
> 
> 
> "C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\Reklamfixarn.sln"
> (default ta rget) (1) -> "C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj" (defaul
> t target) (3) -> (CoreCompile target) ->   PdfService.svc.cs(61,30):
> warning CS0168: The variable 'ex' is declared but n ever used
> [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.cspro
> j]   PdfService.svc.cs(1,1): warning S104: This file has 1172 lines,
> which is grea ter than 1000 authorized. Split it into smaller files.
> [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.
> PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(179,162): warning S105: Replace all tab characters
> in this file by sequences of white-spaces. [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamf ixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(258,1): warning S103: Split this 220 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(273,1): warning S103: Split this 211 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(283,1): warning S103: Split this 211 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(303,1): warning S103: Split this 211 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(313,1): warning S103: Split this 211 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(360,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(384,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(395,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(500,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(511,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(572,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(583,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(596,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(689,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(700,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(772,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(783,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(814,1): warning S103: Split this 212 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(885,1): warning S103: Split this 210 characters long
> line ( which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rek lamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(1001,1): warning S103: Split this 241 characters
> long line (which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Re klamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(1017,1): warning S103: Split this 241 characters
> long line (which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Re klamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(1033,1): warning S103: Split this 241 characters
> long line (which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Re klamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(1048,1): warning S103: Split this 241 characters
> long line (which is greater than 200 authorized). [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Re klamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(100,25): warning S1226: Introduce a new variable
> instead of  reusing the parameter "XMLStr". [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfix arn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(141,21): warning S1226: Introduce a new variable
> instead of  reusing the parameter "XMLStr". [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfix arn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(246,25): warning S131: Add a "default" clause to
> this "swit ch" statement. [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf. csproj]  
> PdfService.svc.cs(1132,35): warning S1481: Remove this unused
> "sbError" local  variable. [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.cspr oj]
> 
> 
> "C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\Reklamfixarn.sln"
> (default ta rget) (1) -> "C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj" (defaul
> t target) (3) -> (RunCodeAnalysis target) ->   MSBUILD : warning
> CA2210: Microsoft.Design : Sign 'PdfWcf.dll' with a strong name key.
> [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.cspro
> j]   MSBUILD : warning CA1045: Microsoft.Design : Consider a design
> that does not require that 'strReturn' be a reference parameter.
> [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFG
> enerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfService.svc.cs(61) :
> warning CA1031: Microsoft.Design : Modify 'PdfService.PdfService()' to
> catch a more specific exception than 'Exception' or rethrow the
> exception. [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfService.svc.cs(55) :
> warning CA1307: Microsoft.Globalization : Because the behavior of
> 'string.End sWith(string)' could vary based on the current user's
> locale settings, replace this call in 'PdfService.PdfService()' with a
> call to 'string.EndsWith(string, StringComparison)'. If the result of
> 'string.EndsWith(string, StringComparison) ' will be displayed to the
> user, such as when sorting a list of items for displ ay in a list box,
> specify 'StringComparison.CurrentCulture' or 'StringCompariso
> n.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase' as the 'StringComparison' parameter. If
> comparing c ase-insensitive identifiers, such as file paths,
> environment variables, or regi stry keys and values, specify
> 'StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase'. Otherwise, if comparing
> case-sensitive identifiers, specify 'StringComparison.Ordinal'. [C
> :\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfService.svc.cs(144
> ): warning CA1031: Microsoft.Design : Modify
> 'PdfService.ConvertPathsInXML(stri ng, string, string)' to catch a
> more specific exception than 'Exception' or ret hrow the exception.
> [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\Pd
> fWcf.csproj]
> 
> 
> 
>   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfService.svc.cs(153
> ): warning CA1502: Microsoft.Maintainability :
> 'PdfService.GeneratePdf(string, string, string, string, ref string,
> bool)' has a cyclomatic complexity of 97. R ewrite or refactor the
> method to reduce complexity to 25. [C:\Sonar db\REC\Post
> en.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfService.svc.cs(112
> 5): warning CA1031: Microsoft.Design : Modify
> 'PdfService.GeneratePdf(string, s tring, string, string, ref string,
> bool)' to catch a more specific exception th an 'Exception' or rethrow
> the exception. [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\R
> eklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfService.svc.cs(110
> 0): warning CA1305: Microsoft.Globalization : Because the behavior of
> 'int.ToSt ring()' could vary based on the current user's locale
> settings, replace this ca ll in 'PdfService.GeneratePdf(string,
> string, string, string, ref string, bool) ' with a call to
> 'int.ToString(IFormatProvider)'. If the result of 'int.ToStrin
> g(IFormatProvider)' will be displayed to the user, specify
> 'CultureInfo.Current Culture' as the 'IFormatProvider' parameter.
> Otherwise, if the result will be s tored and accessed by software,
> such as when it is persisted to disk or to a da tabase, specify
> 'CultureInfo.InvariantCulture'. [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGene
> rator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfService.svc.cs(161
> ): warning CA1307: Microsoft.Globalization : Because the behavior of
> 'string.Co mpare(string, string)' could vary based on the current
> user's locale settings, replace this call in
> 'PdfService.GeneratePdf(string, string, string, string, re f string,
> bool)' with a call to 'string.Compare(string, string, StringCompariso
> n)'. If the result of 'string.Compare(string, string,
> StringComparison)' will b e displayed to the user, such as when
> sorting a list of items for display in a list box, specify
> 'StringComparison.CurrentCulture' or 'StringComparison.Curren
> tCultureIgnoreCase' as the 'StringComparison' parameter. If comparing
> case-inse nsitive identifiers, such as file paths, environment
> variables, or registry key s and values, specify
> 'StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase'. Otherwise, if compa ring
> case-sensitive identifiers, specify 'StringComparison.Ordinal'.
> [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfService.svc.cs(161
> ): warning CA1307: Microsoft.Globalization : Because the behavior of
> 'string.Co mpare(string, string)' could vary based on the current
> user's locale settings, replace this call in
> 'PdfService.GeneratePdf(string, string, string, string, re f string,
> bool)' with a call to 'string.Compare(string, string, StringCompariso
> n)'. If the result of 'string.Compare(string, string,
> StringComparison)' will b e displayed to the user, such as when
> sorting a list of items for display in a list box, specify
> 'StringComparison.CurrentCulture' or 'StringComparison.Curren
> tCultureIgnoreCase' as the 'StringComparison' parameter. If comparing
> case-inse nsitive identifiers, such as file paths, environment
> variables, or registry key s and values, specify
> 'StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase'. Otherwise, if compa ring
> case-sensitive identifiers, specify 'StringComparison.Ordinal'.
> [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj]
> 
> 
> 
> 
>   MSBUILD : warning CA1823: Microsoft.Performance : It appears that
> field 'PdfS ervice.PDFVersion' is never used or is only ever assigned
> to. Use this field or  remove it. [C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csp roj]
> 
> 
> 
>   C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfService.svc.cs(103
> ): warning CA1031: Microsoft.Design : Modify
> 'PdfService.SetHighLowResPicture(b ool, bool, string)' to catch a more
> specific exception than 'Exception' or reth row the exception.
> [C:\Sonar db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Reklamfixarn\PdfWcf\Pdf
> Wcf.csproj]
> 
>     2427 Warning(s)
>     0 Error(s)
> 
> Time Elapsed 00:00:32.93
> 
> Postprocessing:
> 
> %WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently
> be analyse d by SonarQube. File:
> C:\Users\Install\AppData\Local\Temp\2\.NETFramework,Versio
> n=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rekla mfixarn\BL\BL.csproj
> 
> WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently
> be analyse d by SonarQube. File:
> C:\Users\Install\AppData\Local\Temp\2\.NETFramework,Versio
> n=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: C:\Sonar
> db\REC\Posten.PDFGenerator\Rekla mfixarn\PdfWcf\PdfWcf.csproj%/
> 
> 
> 
> 
> 
> sonar-project.properties files are not understood by the SonarQube
> Scanner for M SBuild. Remove those files from the following folders:
> x\Rx) 14:57:00.819  Creating a summary markdown file...
> Post-processing failed. Exit code:1
```

Your feedback will be highly appreciated***

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you are able to successfully analyze some of your .NET projects, but for some others you are getting this "ProjectInfo.xml" error: Is that correct? Can you give more details and the build logs of one of the projects that fails?

Comment: Yes you are right I can analyze many .net project only few project I stuck with this error, I have updated my details, I have shown you build error but if you want some other log file regarding build I dont know where is it exactly placed, except sonar.log, access.log files in the  case required

Comment: In sonarqube I can see log files sonar.log,access.log but where can i find build log? and one more thing what is the alternative which can be done so that sonarqube ignores .xml file to analyse? Or any other alternative to tweek this error?I have updaed my details, any other details kindly tell me since i have to sort this

Comment: You don't need to add a ProjectInfo.xml file to your project. This is a technical file that the SonarQube MSBuild Scanner should itself generate when everything goes as expected.

Comment: can you add the output generated by all steps, "begin", "msbuild" and "end"? you can save all the output to a file by appending `> file.txt` to the command. both sonar.log & access.log are SonarQube server log files and won't be useful to investigate this issue.

Comment: I have added as per your guidence and  warnings i dont care since other program with warning i could analyse but not in this project, Nobody Knows sonar in our company  except me so you are my last hope, developers are blaming build is successful it is the problem in sonarqube, I am helpless, Please dont tell "sorry I cant help you"....If you want other details i can provide you....